# How to order array based on category?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I've got the following array of objects:

```
var source =  [
  {"name": "title_1", "category": "order"},
  {"name": "title_2", "category": "purchase"},
  {"name": "title_3", "category": "order"},
  {"name": "title_4", "category": "detail"},
  {"name": "title_5", "category": "order"},
  {"name": "title_6", "category": "purchase"},
]
```

I need to sort this array out to get elements in order (first - orders, second - detail, third - purchase):

```
console.log(source.sort(function () {
   // todo: ?
}))
```

*Expected result:*

```
[
  {"name": "title_1", "category": "order"},
  {"name": "title_3", "category": "order"},
  {"name": "title_5", "category": "order"},
  {"name": "title_4", "category": "detail"},
  {"name": "title_2", "category": "purchase"},
  {"name": "title_6", "category": "purchase"},
]
```

How to write sort function to get expected result?

Comment: Did you search? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+sort+multiple+properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an object which holds the priority of each category, then sort it based on that object.

```js
const source =  [
  {"name": "title_1", "category": "order"},
  {"name": "title_2", "category": "purchase"},
  {"name": "title_3", "category": "order"},
  {"name": "title_4", "category": "detail"},
  {"name": "title_5", "category": "order"},
  {"name": "title_6", "category": "purchase"},
];

const priority = {
   order: 3,
   detail: 2,
   purchase: 1,
};

const r = source.sort((a, b) => priority[b.category] - priority[a.category]);
console.log(r);
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question, but you did provide a pretty good alternative answer. +1